# How can I convert character entities to display as 'normal' characters in Drupal?

Tags: 6, nodes

I have a customised module that imports items from feeds accessed via a third-party API. The items are used to create nodes for each instance. All the content appears to be importing correctly, but the feed includes character entities like '&amp' in some of the text imported. I've checked the CSVs being imported and the character entities are already in the feed content, so it isn't the module that's causing normal characters to be converted to character entities.

I'd like to know how I can get Drupal to convert the character entities to display as normal characters. Is there a module or setting that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your import module to http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php the text before importing.

Comment: Thanks - the module was developed by a third-party, so this might be problematic in resolving the problem in a timely manner.

Are there any alternative solutions that you know of (short of editing each node and content manually)? If not, then it looks like I'll have to ask the developer and wait on him.