# How can I convert HTML entities imported from CSV via Feeds in to readable characters?

Tags: 6, nodes, feeds, importing-exporting

This relates to a prior question - [How can I convert character entities to display as 'normal' characters in Drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/how-can-i-convert-character-entities-to-display-as-normal-characters-in-drupal)

It looks as if the CSV file itself is imported via Feeds, so I assume that it's Feeds that should 'parse' the HTML entities and convert them in to readable characters (Unicode?).

Is there some sort of extension or patch available for Feeds that can help me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Feeds Tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) allows you to html decode your feeds content before nodes are saved.